# Android change Actionbar background color using AppCompat

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the background color of my ActionBar as well as the title color. I must say I am using the support library.

My styles are as follows.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/red_300</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/red_300</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red_300</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red_700</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

And in styles-v21

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/red_300</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/red_300</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red_300</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Title</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FFFF00</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#FFFF00</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red_700</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

As you guys might see by the amount of attemps to change it, I am already losing my mind. Any clues as to how I can change the ActionBar background and it's title color?

I must note that I am trying this on Android 6.

Comment: to change action bar color, you will have to change primaryColor in your color.xml file. and To change title color. try same you are doing while removing or adding android prefix.

Comment: I do know I can change it via colorPrimary, but I didn't want to change it in the base theme. Any way to do some in a more specific style?

Comment: Have you tried doing it in code?

Answer (score 1):

In the ToolBar creation (xml), setting the `app:theme` fixed it. Specifying a theme there with it's colorPrimary changed the background of the ActionBar without affecting the base theme.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and the theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```